# How can I stop sql query execution in php?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a long SQL query execution. When I close the browser page, sql query (postgresql) execution continues. How can I stop it executing on page closing?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't guarantee that there is a disconnect without JavaScript and the only real way to ensure that you know that the window has closed is to have it continually ping the server -- sometimes the page closing events don't fire. So you'd basically need something in the background tracking the pings and if one does not fire in a given time, call the kill process.

As far as I know, it is not possible to tell a PostgreSQL connection without signing in as an admin and actually forcing the threat to close. The method is called [pg_cancel_backend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-admin.html). I *WOULD NOT* forcibly terminate the process with the command line kill. That could have repercussions which can be avoided by using built in tools.

Comment: Background tracking is interesting idea, but how can background php process know what other php process was disconnected from browser?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to have some javascript that'll pick up on the page close, and perform a postback to the server that will connect to the executing process and stop it.

Comment: That'd only work if the browser is still running -- you'd have to catch when someone closes out of the browser entirely, and account for the browser crashing (which javascript won't do)

Answer (score 0):

You could kill the process on the server.

Comment: I wanted to delete this answer because it's too hardcore and doesn't answer the question, but someone has voted for it. Why? :)

Comment: Because that is the only way to stop a process in a SQL database.  The application only sends the request -- there is no interactive connection between to pause/etc.

Comment: @Gedrox I got you covered. Go for it!

Comment: @OMG Ponies But like Gedrox says, it doesn't answer the question. It doesn't connect the event in the question, closing a browser page, to the desired behavior.

Comment: @user151841: See my comment to Paul about how little that covers

Comment: And what about this magic function – http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php?

Comment: @OMG That Paul's answer doesn't cover all scenarios doesn't make this answer any more complete.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of your question, I'm guessing this is a development machine. If that is the case, just restart the web-server to terminate the php script. If you are using apache, that would look like:

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: Still – how to detect that client has left the page?

Comment: As stated, this is ONLY for use in a development enviroment--you would never want to issue that command on a live server.