# How to stop SQL query execution from client-side using PHP / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, request

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587970/how-can-i-stop-sql-query-execution-in-php) but it is quite old and I am not sure that repeatedly ping the client is the best way to go.

I have a HTML page with a button `START` which performs an AJAX call to another PHP script which itself executes an heavy SQL query. Once this one is done, the result is returned as JSON and Javascript displays it.

I need the user to be able to stop this request, so I added a `STOP` button. How can I make this button stop SQL query (or more generally any running PHP script) on click?

What I thought so far:

- Create an unique `id` while creating the buttons
- Add this `id` to the parameters while making `START` request
- Create a PHP page `abort_request.php` and make the `STOP` button calling it with the unique `id`
- Make `abort_request.php` store the unique `id` into an `aborted` array from `$_SESSION`
- Periodically check from PHP / SQL script if its `id` is contained into the array

Is it a good way to solve this problem or is there some drawback I did not think to?

Comment: Have you tried transactions? Maybe you start one when you click start button, and stop it if you hit stop button... I'm not sure, it's just an idea

Answer (score 0):

I dont know and never have experince with `heavy SQL query` but based at my experience and my research you can stop the execution just by `abort();` the `xmlhttp` or `ajax` that reqruesting the php file that execute sql.

My Test :

index.php

```
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(){
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "mysql.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function stopLoad() {
xmlhttp.abort();
}
```

mysql.php

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("test");
for ($i = 0; $i < 9999; $i ++) {
INSERT INTO `test`.`big-data` (`id`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g`, `h`, `i`, `j`, `k`, `l`, `m`, `n`, `o`, `p`, `q`, `r`, `s`, `t`, `u`, `v`, `w`, `x`, `y`, `z`) VALUES ('', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test');
}
```

Inserting the data took `9.402` second. 
If i stop around 3 second it will stop the execution but still keep the hundreds data that inserted before i stop it.